# How to open website link by clicking on lotus notes mail subject?

Tags: lotus-notes

is there any way to click on the mail subject on lotus notes and direct to the link?

Example :

```
Who      Subject         Date      Size
kit     `food list`       11/09        2k
```

Expected outcome :

when i click on the 'food list', it will redirect to the website link.

Comment: Where's the actual link stored?

Comment: the link can be clicked inside the mail, the actual link is sent via vb.net console log to this email, i dont want to click inside mail to view the link and i want to click the mail subject and redirect to the website.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible. Either you can add some more fields/headers with the mail or have a special subject tag included. 
Then you need to change the queryopen event in the mailbox to check for the field/subject tag, parse the mailbody, open the link end set continue = false to prevent the mail from opening.

A notes only solution would be to send a special form within the email...